# Why am I getting this "bad value for restricted picklist field" in my test class?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, unit-test

When trying to assign values to a multi-picklist field in test class, I'm facing the above error. Please take a look below my controller and test class.

**Controller**

```
    List<String> issues = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(caseDetail.Test__c, List<String>.class);
    for(String strIssue : issues) {
        if(delimiter == '' || delimiter == null) {
            delimiter = strIssue;
        }
        else {
            delimiter += ';' + strIssue;
        }
    }
    NewCaseToUpdate.Test__c = delimiter;
```

**Test class :**

```
    List<String> issueList = new List<String>();
    issueList.add('Engineering Samples');
    testCase.Test__c = JSON.serialize(issueList);
```

Comment: You are setting an invalid picklist value to `Test__c`, please add one of a valid value.

Comment: Usually, the first step would be to add some `system.debug()` lines so you can get an idea of what data variables hold, what the result of a boolean operation is, etc... Setting that aside, is there a reason why you're not using `String.join()` in your controller?

Comment: @Rahul, 'Engineering Samples' is a valid picklist value in that field

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to serialize a string list into a JSON list to store the values in your field. Multi-picklist fields use the `;` character to separate the selected values.

You are trying to assign a list like this:

```
["Engineering Samples"]
```

While your field likely expects just a single value like this:

```
"Engineering Samples"
```

Or, if you want to test multiple values, you should assign them like this:

```
"Engineering Samples"; Others; "Butterfly Samples"
```

Notice: they are separated by `;`. If a value does not contain a space, and if it isn't even surrounded by double quotes.

From [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/field_types.htm):

> Multi-select picklist fields contain a list of one or more items from which a user can choose multiple items. One of the items can be configured as the default item. Selections are maintained as a string containing a series of attributes delimited by semicolons. For example, a query can return the values of a multivalue picklist as “first value; second value; third value”. For information on querying multi-select picklists, see Querying Multi-Select Picklists in the Salesforce SOQL and SOSL Reference Guide.

More here: [Querying Multi-Select Picklists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm?search_text=picklist).